# SASS Source Map pointing to the wrong SASS file

Tags: css, sass

I have 4 SASS files `main.sass`, `_fonts.sass`, `_variables.sass`, `_home.sass`.

main.sass

```
@import 'fonts'
@import 'variables'
@import 'home'
```

_fonts.sass

```
@font-face
    font-family: "FontAwesome"
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal
    src: url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0")
    src: url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg")
```

_variables.sass

```
$yellow: #fce001
```

_home.sass

```
.container
    color: $yellow
    text-align: right

.another-container
    color: $yellow
    text-align: center

    &:after
        content: '\f0b0'
        font-family: FontAwesome
        font-style: normal
        font-weight: normal
        text-decoration: inherit
        position: absolute
        right: 20px
        display: inline-block
        font-size: 1.1em
```

Here's my sample HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>hello</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        container
    </div>
    <div class="another-container">
        another-container
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm compiling my SASS file using this command: `sass --watch main.sass:style.css`

When I check my google chrome inspect element to `container` or `another-container`, its pointing to `_variables.sass` NOT `_home.sass`. `_variables.sass` only contain variables. I want it to point to `_home.sass`.

@update
I managed to pinpoint what is causing the error, in the `_home.sass` in `content: '\f0b0'`, if I remove this the source map is pointing to the correct line, why is this causing the error?

Comment: how are you compiling sass ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, see my updated question

Comment: rename your file home.sass to _home.sass and compiled again

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, the error is still there, I updated my question again.

Comment: Do you use `GEM` `Sass` ? or you are using `Node-Sass`?

Comment: @AmerllicA, i'm not sure, `node-sass` i think?? How do i determine what sass i'm using?

Comment: When I type `sass --version` it outputs `1.9.0 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0-dev.67.0`

Comment: please pack your project with archive and then send for me `amerllica@gmail.com`, I will see it and tell you.

Comment: I'm not the one who installed sass on this computer. Ok will send you the code

Comment: send the whole project. I will help you dude, don't worry.

Comment: already sent my project

Comment: try with this command sass --watch main.sass:style.css --sourcemap @aceraven777

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, nope doesn't work, i think by default `--source-map` is implied

Comment: @aceraven777 delete the old one file and generate again by compiling

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, already tried that also. Same problem

Comment: @aceraven777 did you tried gulp-sass

Comment: try to import home.sass in first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using gulp-sass and gulp-sourcemaps package with below gulpfile.js to render the sass file with source-map

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('*.sass')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check another browser like Firefox or Safari and it's displaying the source maps correctly then I'd recommend clearing the cache and/or exiting Chrome and firing it up again. This has happened to me on occasion with Chrome and this is how I've been able to resolve it.

Comment: I've done this already doesn't work. By default firefox doesn't have SASS support in the inspect element. If you read my question if i remove the CSS property `content: '\f0b0'`, the source map is displaying correctly. I don't think it has to do with the browser.

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't refreshed this tab and then posted my answer so didn't see the update where you identified what's causing it. Haven't encountered that issue before but here are some things to try: 1) adding a space to the end of the FontAwesome unicode e.g. `content: '\f0b0 '` ... 2) `content: unquote('\f0b0 ')` ... 3) Declare `@charset 'utf-8';`